# Distance between axis number and axis in MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I struggle a little bit with overlapping axis numbers of the y and x axis like it is shown in the image. I'd like to keep the size of the numbers and therefore think that simply shifting the numbers away from the axis itself would be an appropriate way to handle this issue.

Is there a possibility to do that[image]?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little workaround using text annotations. Basically you clear the current XTick labels and replace them with similar labels, but you can specify the distance from the axis:

```
clc
clear
close all

x = 1:20;

hPlot = plot(x,sin(x));

set(gca,'xaxisLocation','top');

set(gca,'XTickLabel',[]); %// Clear current XTickLabel

ylim = get(gca,'YLim'); %// Get y limit of the plot to place your text annotations.

for k = 2:2:20
    text(k,ylim(2)+0.1,num2str(k),'HorizontalAlignment','Center') %// Play with the 'ylim(1) -0.1' to place the label as you wish.
end
```

Giving this:

[image]

Of course now it's exaggerated and you can do the same for the y axis if you want (using the 'XLim' property of the current axis,gca).

Comment: So @Josef did you try my suggestion??

Comment: Hi Benoit,
sry that it took me so long to answer. Your workaround is working just fine for me. I'm just wondering if there is a more direct way to do it. 
But thank you very much anyway.
Joe

Comment: ok sure no problem! There might be some way with java stuff but I doubt it's more direct than that :P Anyhow glad it worked.